# Can someone explain how did they get this with two's complement?

Tags: binary

[binary photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SgmQ.png)
I get last three sequences , but shouldn't it continue being 0000, instead of 1111

Comment: What is `1110 + 0001`? Remember that binary arithmetic works exactly the same as decimal arithmetic, including carry.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes but this is two's complement there is third 1 down below, doesn't 1 transfer to other side as well so its 1+0+1

Comment: The first line seems to be the original value. The second line is the inversion of the first. Then one is added to the *inversion*, giving the result shown in the last line.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude u are right, lol tnx a lot